# Node redirecting to https

Tags: node.js

I have a demo site setup in node. If I access it via `ip:port`, I can access it and if I try to access it via `domain name`, it gets redirected to https and becomes inaccessible.
I have this code in my server.js file:

```
app.use(function(req, res, next) {
    if( (process.env.NODE_ENV == 'production') && (!req.secure) && (req.get('X-Forwarded-Proto') !== 'https')) {
        res.redirect('https://' + req.get('Host') + req.url);
    }
    else
        next();
});
```

I don't have a `NODE_ENV` variable setup and even if I delete this piece of code, redirection still happens.

How can I make this to work on http along with the domain name?

Comment: **res.redirect('https://' + req.get('Host') + req.url);** ... might be the issue ..try changing the https ..to http only..

Comment: Doesn't help..as I said even if I remove the whole code, the issue persists.

Comment: The code you show apparently has nothing to do with your issue (since removing it does not change the behavior).  Are you running both an http and an https server?  That's the only way to make a site work on both protocols.

Comment: I've installed node and started the app with forever
/usr/bin/nohup /usr/local/bin/forever server.js > outputerr.log